# What was missing that kept Stargate Command from making their own Stargates?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

The SGC understood the functions of a dial-home device and was able to create their own when the gate they had didn't have a DHD.

I remember in one or two episodes there were issues that led to characters (like Samantha Carter) having to fix a Stargate.  It looks like they had a clear understanding, at least after several years, of how the gate worked and what it took to repair it (in some situations).

Was there something, in particular, that was missing that kept the SGC from building their own Stargates?  Perhaps a need for a rare material the gate needed?  Or did they never reach the level of understanding of how a stargate worked to actually be able to build one?

Comment: Keep in mind the DHD they built was rudimentary, and did not fully and/or properly account for or utilize all the functions/properties of the gate. There were one or two episodes where this fact actually figured prominently into the plot.

Comment: Yes. Carter said this. The gates actually have a rich set of API functions which the SGC DHD couldn't use. It's a macro of these that McKay used for the forwarding part of the gate bridge.

Comment: I think there may have also been an occasion or two where someone not of earth mocked their "primitive" attempt at creating a dialing program. At least one such occasion being Baal, iirc.

Comment: @eidylon - There was also an extraterrestrial who complemented them on building it themselves. I think the Goa'uld act unimpressed as part of their image

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They could never repair or build the wormhole device itself (i.e. the ring).

They always fixed either the software, the power supply, the DHD or various other connectivity/circuit issues. They had enough Naquadah (the main Stargate 'ingredient') and knew how to make a rudimentary reactor out of it. A fallen Ancient once built a mini-Stargate right inside Cater's house with items ordered off the Internet. So it's not material.

So it comes down to not knowing the design and (and perhaps the working principles) of the wormhole generating device.

P.S. This brings up a far more intriguing question (perhaps it should be a separate question?): They knew how to reprogram Stargates for different locations. They did that with the McKay-Carter Intergalactic Gate Bridge. So why build Stargates? Just pick one up from an uninhabited planet, reprogram it and keep it at SGC as a backup.

Comment: They didn't even need to do that much.  The Gate system is coordinate-based, and as seen in SG-1 6x01 - 6x02 _Redemption_, moving a Stargate was enough to make it incompatible with the given coordinates.  They're adaptive enough that I expect moving one _to_ a location would also simply just work.

Comment: @Iskata So long as you knew the coordinates for that location anyway.

Comment: but weren't the symbols different on different gates?  How would you do the point of origin?

Comment: @AidanO: Each gate had a unique symbol that was it's point of origin.

Comment: @AidanO interesting. Perhaps the human-readable symbol is different, but in the gate's machine code, it boils down to a single code on each gate. Otherwise the McCay-Carter gate bridge could not have worked.

Comment: @HNL: While I watched all of SG1, I don't remember an Ancient building the mini-gate.  Do you remember what episode that was in?

Comment: @TangoOversway "Ascension" it's the third episode of the fifth season.

Comment: @Jeff So would that mean that all the other symbols were the same? just the point of origin was different?  I'm not sure how that works out with the theory in the Film, that the symbols match starsigns, as they would be different on different planets.

Comment: @AidanO - the show was only loosely based upon the film. And I've heard it stated that as of last plans, if they ever complete the film trilogy, they will essentially dismiss all the TV work and not consider any of it canon. Though that could easily change. This is why the movie and show don't always match up. Just think, if the symbols were different on every planet, there's no way the characters could quickly re-dial earth. They'd first need to do detailed studies of the stars from that planet's view, and figure out its coordinate system. Would be an episodic drag.

Comment: @AidanO: Thanks -- this is weird.  That's when SG1 was still on Showtime and I know I saw every episode, especially before they went over to Skiffy.

Comment: @eidylon: I don't know about that. If you know all the common symbols then identifying the point of origin is just a matter of looking for the symbol you haven't seen before. This was a plot point in season one's "Solitudes".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - weren't the symbols in the movie though based upon the constellations from the local planet? Which would mean that all the symbols would be completely different on each planet?

Comment: @eidylon: Just because the symbols matched constellations-as-seen-from-Earth doesn't mean that the glyphs had to hold an inherent mathematical meaning based on the shape of the glyph. The series established that the gate network's symbology was based on Earth stellar cartography, but any correlation beyond this has never been shown; in the film, I can't remember whether the Abydos gate had all different glyphs, though Daniel's difficulty in finding the point-of-origin may indeed suggest this.

Comment: The symbols located a region in space, the wormhole would latch onto any ring that happened to be near that region. there were various times when another ring was moved and took priority over the normal gate of a system.

Comment: I think early episodes (possibly only the initial two-parter) made a point of working out how to dial home again... I guess they eventually came up with a better way after hitting a few planets and becoming more experienced.

Answer (score 2):

Sam Carter had an encounter with one of the Ancients in season 5 episode 3 of SG-1, and he had built a rudimentary Stargate in her basement from items he ordered online. They literally had an ingredients list, as well as the physical gate itself in Sam's basement. I see no reason why they couldn't have started developing wormhole technology.

Comment: It burned itself out and contained things that weren't easy for humans to make (such as a fist-sized ruby). At the end it was likely investigated but not easy to replicate

Comment: Plus the "ingredients list" is incomplete. He's cannibalised various items from her house as well.

Comment: @Valorum artificial rubies were first made in 1837. A fist-sized crystal should be pretty easy these days.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, but try getting just *that* arrangement of the chromium atoms.